# LXML 3.3 with Python 3.3 on windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, windows-7, pip, lxml, 32-bit

I am having major issues with this install.  Please provide a detailed, **step-by-step guide**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**These instructions are for Windows7 or Windows8 with Python3.3**.

**However**, they should work for various versions as the releases of python and other respective prerequisites change/evolve:

1. Install ***Python3.3***:

   1. Download the last release of Python3.3 (currently 3.3.5) from the downloads page [HERE](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/)

      - Direct link for Win32 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.msi)
   2. Simply run the MSI to install python.  It will register itself in the registry, and appear in Add/REmove Programs.
   3. **NOTE:** my instructions that follow assume that you choose to install python to the default path of `C:\python33\` when asked during the Python Installation Wizard
2. Add the `C:\python33\` and `C:\python33\scripts` folders to the system path by adding those directories to the `PATH` environment variable from the **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings link (Advanced Tab) > Environmental Variables (Button)**.
3. Install ***OpenSSL***:

   1. Download **Win32 OpenSSL page** from [HERE](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Download **Visual C++ 2008 redistributables** for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   3. Download **OpenSSL** for your version of Windows and architecture (the regular version, not the light one)
   4. Add the `c:\openssl-win32\bin` (or similar) directory to your `PATH`, the same way you added `C:\python33` and `C:\python33\scripts` above.
4. Install ***Setuptools*** (`get-pip.py` should install Setuptools for you), but, just in case...

   1. Download `ez_setup.py` [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python ez_setup.py`**
5. Install ***PIP***

   1. Download `get-pip.py` from [HERE](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python get-pip.py`**
6. Install ***LXML***

   1. Download `LXML 3.3.3` from [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Run the EXE file