# Installing lxml for Python 3.4 on Windows x 86 (32 bit) with Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, lxml

### Related

Related questions:

- [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869/1175496)
- [LXML 3.3 with Python 3.3 on windows 7 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22981951/1175496)

Related answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045219/1175496

Related comments:

- [Building lxml for Python 2.7 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047542/building-lxml-for-python-2-7-on-windows#comment-26574146)
- "@ziyuang This would mean you use Python 3.3 which uses Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. If that's the case then the answer is yes, you should install this version."

### Facts

- Windows x86 (32-bit)
- Installed both Visual Studio C++ 2008 ([from here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/5/4/A54BADB6-9C3F-478D-8657-93B3FC9FE62D/vcsetup.exe)) Express and Visual Studio C++ 2010 ([from here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709949))
- Python 3.4.1 (apparently compiled **with newer version** than Visual Studio 2008)
- I use pip (or pip3.4.exe; builtin to Python 3.4) to `pip install lxml`
- distutils uses Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express to compile

The last few lines of my error, logged by pip:

> cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
>
> lxml.etree.c
>
> C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_nathanielanderson\lxml\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(9)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h':
>   No such file or directory
>
> C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown
>   distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
>
> warnings.warn(msg)
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

So I can't install from the .egg or by compiling...

### Other Options

I also can't find Windows installer (exe or msi or whatever) for this version of Python

- Not [here at PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3)
- <s>Nor [here at Chris' great site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)</s>

**Update 10/16/2019**

As commenter says, the executable links are no longer available

- [This archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140911135250/http://www.lfd.uci.edu:80/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (from 2014; executable links don't work) shows the old links
- As commenter says; [the site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)  currently has `whl` (wheel) files for the `lxml` library; you can [use `pip` to install from `whl` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/1175496)
- Or check out [this set of links](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.3.5/#files) to executable files on `pypi.org`; the executables only range from 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, and 3.4

<s>Looks like Chris **does** provide a direct exe here:</s>

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Thanks, Chris! Any ideas why I cannot compile using pip?

Comment: "Looks like Chris does provide a direct exe here: (link)"

Where?? I don't see any exe for LXML, only wheel files. Was it removed?

Comment: Hi @Calydon, you're right... I don't know what to suggest. The old executable links don't work. Maybe installing from the `whl` files is straightforward and can be done instead of `exe`. Otherwise [try this site](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.3.5/#files) (thanks to accepted answer)

Comment: In the end I was able to get the 3.8 whl to work (as you'd expect with Python3.8). Not sure if it was there when I first looked. These types of technical hangups are the bane of inexperienced programmers. Python should 'just work'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also got this problem, but the workarounds provided above are not work for me as well.

Here is my system configuration:

- Win7 64bit
- python3.3
- visual studio 2013

I tried to use the method in the first link in the **Related questions**, but it's fail. This method is to create a system variable for vs2010 use, and the variable is actually copy from my original configuration in visual studio 2013.

However, the command line prompted error with "libxml/xmlversion.h" no suck file or directory

Then I further searched it on the internet and got a method which works in my case.

1. downloading the precompiled lxml plugin

   **Precompiled lxml 3.5**: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5#downloads

   if your system is 64bit, then you can get a unofficial version for x64 at here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml (this is what i use)
2. installing with command in command line ***easy_install lxml-3.2.1.win32-py3.3.‌exe***

   **Reference**: https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1520

Comment: Yes I needed Gohlke, per my question. Sounds like you needed Gohlke also, per your specs:64bit. Did you need Gohlke? Which version of lxml would you recommend? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml lists a few; why does your answer mention 3.3.5? Finally, why use easy_install on the executable, can't you just open the executable? Thanks.

Comment: 1. yes, as i said i use lxml 3.4.1 Gohlke version which is a unofficial version     
2. actually, i am a newcomer who just start to learn this plugin. sorry for that     

3. ver 3.3.5 is what i looked for at first, but there is no any available component for python 3.3     

4. i think you can, i have tried to execute it after reading your question... it can detect successfully the python3.3 installed in my system in the prepossessing announcement. but i didn't really make the installation process since i already installed it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Download precompiled lxml from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml works for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using python 3.4 this is the download link :

[Download Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/4jci5y59/lxml-3.4.1.win32-py3.4.exe)

If you have any other configuration find it [HERE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) according to your need. ;-)

Comment: tried lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win32.whl on windows 7 from the second link. works like a charm.

Comment: Using the above link to Gohlke's site, I could NOT install the win32 version, but was successful (on my 64-bit Intel-based Windows system) with the win_amd64 version. Download the whl file to c:\Python34\Scripts, then run `c:\Python34\Scripts>pip install "lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"`
Results:
Unpacking c:\python34\scripts\lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl  
Installing collected packages: lxml  

Successfully installed lxml  

Cleaning up...

Answer (score 3):

The short version is: You need to have the C library `libxml2` (and also `libxslt2`) before you can build `lxml`.

---

As the [`lxml` installation docs](http://lxml.de/installation.html) say:

> Unless you are using a static binary distribution (e.g. from a Windows binary installer), you need to install `libxml2` and `libxslt`, in particular:
>
> - `libxml2` 2.6.21 or later. It can be found here: http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html
>
>   - We recommend `libxml2 2.7.8 or a later version.
>   - If you want to use XPath, do not use `libxml2` 2.6.27.
>   - If you want to use the feed parser interface, especially when parsing from unicode strings, do not use `libxml2` 2.7.4 through 2.7.6.
> - `libxslt` 1.1.15 or later. It can be found here: http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/downloads.html
>
>   - We recommend `libxslt` 1.1.26 or later.

The [build from source docs](http://lxml.de/build.html) similarly start off with:

> To build lxml from source, you need libxml2 and libxslt properly installed, including the header files.

---

Windows (unlike most other platforms) doesn't come with these libraries. You don't mention anything in your "Facts" about having them.

---

And the error message that you showed is:

```
C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_nathanielanderson\lxml\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(9) : 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': 
No such file or directory
```

That `'libxml/xmlversion.h'` that it can't find is part of `libxml2`.

---

It's also worth noting that the same installation docs explicitly say:

> consider using the binary builds from PyPI or the unofficial Windows binaries that Christoph Gohlke generously provides.

So, the fact that you thought Christoph Gohlke didn't provide binaries for `lxml` implies that you hadn't found these docs.

---

So, it's possible that you did install `libxml2`, but not in a way that `lxml2`'s setup script can find it. But all the evidence implies it's a lot more likely that you just don't have it.