# Error downloading scrapy, lxml error

Tags: python, scrapy, lxml

```
  Failed building wheel for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Family\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i6gpylsx\\
lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Family\AppData
\Local\Temp\pip-jggq15oq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.4.4.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b'xslt-config \x84r inte ett internt kommando, externt kommando,\r\nprogram eller kommandofil.\r\n'
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo
 /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i6gpyl
sx\lxml\src\lxml\includes -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcsrc\lxml\
lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i6gpylsx\lxml\src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14) :
        fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='C:\\Users\\Family\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-i6gpylsx\\lxml\\setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))"
install --record C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jggq15oq
-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed
 with error code 1 in C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-i6gpylsx\lxml
```

I have Python 3.4 on a 64-bit computer. Searched a lot on stack overflow and nothing helped me. I have no idea what's wrong and do you know any solutions?

Comment: Avoid posting links to external sites. Here's how to create an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited it and just used the last part.

Comment: Do you have C installed?

Comment: C? What do you mean by do you have C installed? If you mean Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy does not work with Python 3 currently, but there are plans (and even work in progress) to do this port. So I would suggest you to install Python 2.7 to your computer too and install the required libraries there too.

For `lxml` and other libraries there are some unofficial ports for windows which you can look at [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

And sometimes you need some free Visual Studio downloaded and installed to get libraries on your windows machine which enable to compile lxml. You can find a related question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944465/installing-lxml-for-python-3-4-on-windows-x-86-32-bit-with-visual-studio-c-2).