# Errors while installing with pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, lxml

I am trying install lxml but getting the below error, I am using a windows box:

Command:
    pip install lxml

Error:

> You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.0 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade
>   pip' comm and. Collecting lxml   Using cached lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: lxml   Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for lxml   Complete output from command
>   C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;**fi
>   le**='c:\users\monang~1.kum\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-fpxxjd\lxml\set
>   up.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
>   **file**, 'exec '))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\monang~1.kum\appdata\local\temp\tmp6l4_jopip-wheel- :

Comment: just search lxml windows binary in google?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks for the link, problem solved:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by ivan_pozdeev, this can be resolved by installing the pre-compiled **lxml** plugin [Precompiled lxml 3.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5#downloads)

OR:
installing with command in command line **easy_install lxml-3.2.1.win32-py3.3.‌exe**

Link-->1.  [Installing lxml for Python 3.4 on Windows x 86 (32 bit) with Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944465/installing-lxml-for-python-3-4-on-windows-x-86-32-bit-with-visual-studio-c-2)
2. https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1520

Answer (score 0):

Install [libxml](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libxml2.htm) and try again .